# django template - if True returns false?

Tags: django, django-templates

i have this code:

```
{% if True %}
    yo!
{% else %}
    what?
{% endif %}
```

and the output is, of course, `what?` (of course, because i wouldn't ask the question otherwise, would i?)

does `True` not exist in the template world?

Comment: I never realized this was the case. Do you have a use case relying on "if True"? or just something you came across?

Comment: just something i came across - i don't have much use for  an if True myself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is kind of funny, and could possibly be considered a bug, but I imagine it has to do with the way template tags are processed. The first parameter to `if` is likely being treated as a context variable, so it's looking up `True` in the context dict, and of course, getting nothing because there's no `True` key.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you don't have the `True` object in your context, so it resolves to falsehood. Django templates aren't simple Python wrappers. You won't have the usual `globals()` objects, `True` included.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the related `ifequal` tag says:

> It is only possible to compare an argument to template variables or
>   strings. You cannot check for equality with Python objects such as
>   True or False. If you need to test if something is true or false, use
>   the if tag instead.

This could suggest that True and False indeed do not exist in Django templates unless you create them as such using a custom context processor.